# How to Validate Form in Name section using regex expressions

Tags: javascript, html, regex

How to Validate Form in Name section using regex expression   `/^[a-zA-Z]{2,20}$/` ?

I want the user to enter their name in either a-z or A-Z with no less than 2 characters and no more than 20.

Can someone help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Can Validate Input</h2>

<p>Please input a number between 1 and 10: <input id="numb"> <span id="demo"></span> </p>
<p>Please input your name <input id="name"> <span id="demo2"></span></p> 

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
    var x, text;
    var y, text2;

        // Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
    x = document.getElementById("numb").value;
    y = document.getElementById("name").value;

// If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 10
if (x == ""){
    text = "Age must be filled out.";
}
else if (isNaN(x) || x < 1 || x > 10) {
    text = "Digits only or enter age between 10 and 120.";}
else {
    text = "Age Input OK";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;

if ( y == ""){
text2 = "Name must be filled out.";
}
```

** This following line is where I where I need the help: **

```
else if (y != /^[a-zA-Z]{2,20}$/){
text2= "Enter letters 2 to 20 only";
}

///
else {
text2 = "name is ok";
}
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = text2;
}
```

Comment: "I know that there is regExp". Yes, you need to use some Function or method that tests that string for the regex

Answer (score 0):

use javascript `test` method that works on regex

```js
else if (/^[a-zA-Z]{2,20}$/.test(y){
text2= "Enter letters 2 to 20 only";
}
```

or for better code readability use this

```js
const testRegex = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,20}$/
else if (testRegex.test(y){
text2= "Enter letters 2 to 20 only";
}
```

#### update: not supporting number

if you don't want a number you can use the below regex

```js
const with_no_numbers = /^[a-zA-Z\D]{2,20}$/
```

Comment: I tried the 'else if' statement you provided; however, regardless of what is placed in the input field, the result will accept anything whether it is a number or one letter entered. The key is to not accept numbers, and to not accept less than 2 letters or more than 20.
The 'const testRegex' does not work at all for some reason, it renders the both inputs useless or not showing any result.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable and assign regular expression pattern to variable. Then use search() function to evaluate the input.

```
// variable = pattern expression:
 
reg = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,20}$/;

// change else if statement to:

else if (y.search(reg)){ 
    text2= "Enter letters 2 to 20 only";
}
```